# Can I stick with ASP.Net and move from EF6 to EF Core?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am starting to port a EF6 application to EF Core. The app also uses `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`. However I am unable to find if it is possible to use that package with EF Core. It seems like I need to use 
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`, but this seem to force me to move to Asp.Net Core.

Is it possible to avoid that, i.e. Can I stick with AspNet and move from EF6 to EF Core or do I have to move from AspNet to Asp.Net Core at the same time? I have tried to find an answer in the docs, so any pointers would be helpfull!

Comment: In theory yes, since it has no dependencies on .NET Core or ASP.NET Core. However, there are a few catches. EF Core is made with Dependency Injection in mind and as such it can't be used with a parameterless constructor the way EF 6 was (`using(var context = new MyDbContext())`, so you would have to inject the `DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>` into your classes and pass that when `new` ing or do that in the composition root and inject the instance.

Comment: May also makes thing easier if you replace your DI with the new Microsoft DI one but I don't think that'd be necessary, but would help with registrations of the new .NET Standard libraries with the `IServiceCollection` extension method registrations. Still you can use `IServiceCollection` with a IoC Container of your choice, some can use the `IServiceCollection` to do initial registrations (i.e. autofac) and rest you can do with the AutoFac methods (such as Assembly Scans)

Comment: @Tseng The central problem I currently have is my dependency on `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`. Do you know if there is a nuget package which provides the same, but for `EntityFrameworkCore`?

Comment: Not that I know of, but Identity uses stores [see here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework). You can implement them yourself, but use EF Core inside it instead of EF6. You would have to re-implement at least `IdentityDbContext`, `UserStore`, `RoleStore` and have your classes inherit from these

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to move your entire application to use the .NET Core because .NET Full Framework can reference .NET Core libraries. The opposite is also true, NET Core 2.0+ can reference full .NET Framework libraries.

However, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` is dependent on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` and will not be able to 'talk' to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`, at a minimum you would need to isolate your other dependencies on `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`. It's not readily apparent if you will run into any conflicts but I would err on the side of caution and refactor your (Full .NET Framework) application to only depend on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` (Instead of both AspNet and AspNetCore simultaneously) which is completely feasible.